# kohana find the second element of a collection (using find())

Tags: orm, find, kohana

i have a kohana website and i have a situation where i always need to get the first two elements of a collection (they are actually pictures).

i take the first element very simple using :

```
     $image = $product->images->find();
```

but how can i actually take the second element? (using find eventually). Is there any easy solution for that?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$first_two = $product->images->limit(2)->find_all();
```

find() is basically the same as find_all(), adding a limit(1) and returning the current result (first one).

```
$first = current($first_two);
$second = next($first_two);
```

Notice that next() advances the internal array pointer so you'll have to reset() it if you want to loop from the start again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limit($n)` and `offset($o)` combination to select `$n` rows starting from `$o` position in DB. Read more about Query Builder methods [here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/query/builder).

So, your code will looks like `$image = $product->images->offset(1)->find();`

PS. Note than some DB engines may not support SQL's `OFFSET` statement (MS SQL server for example).

Comment: though the title says otherwise, she asked how to "get the first two elements" :)